# Java code migration error using com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I am using Java code and converting the code in ColdFusion. There are some challenges where I am stuck. This is one function I have in Java:

```
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;
import net.minidev.json.JSONArray;
import net.minidev.json.JSONStyle;

private static String getDetails(String instaDetailsElement) {
   String jsonResponse = instaDetailsElement.split(" = ")[1];
   JSONArray mediaArray = JsonPath.read(jsonResponse, "$.entry_data.PostPage[:1].graphql.shortcode_media");
   String returnJsonString = mediaArray.toJSONString(new JSONStyle(JSONStyle.FLAG_IGNORE_NULL));
   System.out.println(returnJsonString);
   return returnJsonString;
}
```

These two lines are giving me some trouble:

```
var mediaArray = JsonPath.read(jsonResponse, "$.entry_data.PostPage[:1].graphql.shortcode_media");
var returnJsonString = mediaArray.toJSONString(new JSONStyle(JSONStyle.FLAG_IGNORE_NULL));
```

Here is what I attempted so far. I loaded the jar library for JSON path and tried using it like this:

**Application.cfc settings**

```
<cfset this.javaSettings = {LoadPaths = ["cfc/jar"], loadColdFusionClassPath = true, reloadOnChange = false}>
```

**CF Code:**

```
public any function getDetails(String instaDetailsElement) {
        var jsonResponse = instaDetailsElement.split(" = ")[1];
        var JsonPath = Createobject("java","com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath");
        writedump(application);
        var mediaArray = JsonPath.read(jsonResponse, "$.entry_data.PostPage[:1].graphql.shortcode_media");
        writedump(mediaArray); abort;
        var returnJsonString = mediaArray.toJSONString(new JSONStyle(JSONStyle.FLAG_IGNORE_NULL));
        return returnJsonString;
    }
```

I'm able to view the class methods when I dump the JsonPath object ([screen shot](https://prnt.sc/etYepbGVjASF)), but when I try to call JsonPath.read() I get this error:

> No matching Method for read(string, string) found for
> com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath

Comment: `JSONStyle` is a java class.  You must create an instance of it in order to use it.  Start by reading [Converting Java Code Examples to CFML](https://cfdocs.org/java) and [Using Java in Lucee](https://docs.lucee.org/guides/Various/tutorial-lucee/tutorial-java-in-lucee.html)  which explain how to create an instance of JSONStyle and other classes in that snippet. Then try to do that.  If you run into problems, post what new you've actually attempted and any error messages.

Comment: there is an open-source project called JMES Path that will provide a solution similar to what you are looking for and here is a library in pure CFML https://github.com/scottsteinbeck/jmespath.

Comment: it seems to be using coldbox and i am not using coldbox, how i am suppose to use the wirebox thing

Comment: i loaded the jar files for jsonpoath in my java directory and loaded it and tried using it but i am getting this `No matching Method for read(string, string) found for com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath`, even i dumped the class instance to check if the jar is properly uploaded, it is but it is unable to read the method value,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Since this has turned into two questions in one thread, I'm separating the second answer out for clarity ...)

> `var returnJsonString = mediaArray.toJSONString(new JSONStyle(JSONStyle.FLAG_IGNORE_NULL));`

As for translating the JSONStyle code, it helps to unpack nested code from the inside out. Then tackle each piece separately:

1. mediaArray.toJSONString(new JSONStyle( **JSONStyle.FLAG_IGNORE_NULL** ));
2. mediaArray.toJSONString( **new JSONStyle(** JSONStyle.FLAG_IGNORE_NULL **)** )
3. **mediaArray.toJSONString(** new JSONStyle( JSONStyle.FLAG_IGNORE_NULL ) **)**

**Piece #1**

Uses a static *field* of the [JSONStyle](https://javadoc.io/doc/net.minidev/json-smart/latest/index.html) class named `FLAG_IGNORE_NULL`. To access the field, create a reference to that class:

```
JsonStyle = createObject("java", "net.minidev.json.JSONStyle");  
writeDump(JSONStyle.FLAG_IGNORE_NULL);
```

**Piece #2**

Creates a brand new *instance* of the [JSONStyle](https://javadoc.io/doc/net.minidev/json-smart/latest/index.html) class, using the static field from above. Use createObject() to create the new instance, passing the static field into the psuedo constructor init():

```
 newJsonStyle = createObject("java", "net.minidev.json.JSONStyle").init(JSONStyle.FLAG_IGNORE_NULL);
 writeDump( newJsonStyle );
```

**Piece #3**

All that's left is calling the [JSONArray.toJSONString()](https://javadoc.io/doc/net.minidev/json-smart/latest/index.html)  method with the JSONStyle object you just created:

```
 result = mediaArray.toJSONString( newJsonStyle );
 writeDump(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR;**

> No matching method for `read(string, string)` found for *com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath*

Technically the error message is correct: there is no read() method that accepts two strings (even though that's how it's used in the java code).  The method actually expects *three* arguments:

[image: image of read method]

Pass in an empty array for the 3rd argument:

```
JsonPath.read(jsonResponse, "$.entry_data.PostPage[:1].graphql.shortcode_media", []);
```

---

**Explanation:**

> ```
> String jsonResponse = instaDetailsElement.split(" = ")[1];
> JsonPath.read(jsonResponse, "$.entry_data.PostPage[:1].graphql.shortcode_media")
> ```

If there really is no `read(String, String)` method, you might wonder why the java code works at all, since that's exactly what it uses. It works due to a special feature of java.

The [documentation](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.jayway.jsonpath/json-path/latest/com/jayway/jsonpath/JsonPath.html) shows the overloaded read(..) method actually has *three* parameters, but one of them is special:

```
read(String json,
     String jsonPath,
     Predicate... filters)
```

Notice the `...` after the class name (Predicate)? It's a construct called ["varargs"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java///javaOO/arguments.html) (or variable number of arguments):

> *You can use a construct called varargs to pass an arbitrary number of values to a method. You use varargs when you don't know how many of a
> particular type of argument will be passed to the method. It's a
> shortcut to creating an array manually ...*
>
> *To use varargs, you follow the type of the last parameter by an ellipsis (three dots, ...), then a space, and the parameter name. **The
> method can then be called with any number of that parameter,
> including none**.*

So in java you're allowed to omit the third argument entirely and call `read(String, String)` with two strings. ColdFusion doesn't support that syntax, because it creates too much ambiguity. So in lieu of omitting the argument, you can pass in an empty array instead:

```
JsonPath.read(jsonResponse, "$.entry_data.PostPage[:1].graphql.shortcode_media", []);
```

Comment: oh nice, i got the arrayhasmap using the technique you told me, now if you can help, there is another part which is `var returnJsonString = mediaArray.toJSONString(new JSONStyle(JSONStyle.FLAG_IGNORE_NULL));`, now i have the json-smart.jar file loaded in my code, but now the concern is, it uses the new style, what should i be doing in this case

Comment: https://prnt.sc/VfhWqbEw6Y4n how my JSONstyle looks like